# Erro no PIVOT SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Galera, estou com um problema na estrutura do meu PIVOT.

```
DECLARE @IdGiaContribuinte INT = 0,
         @IdGrupoContribuinte INT = 0,
         @Exercicio INT = 2017,
         @IdVafvalorAdicionadoTipo INT = 3


    SELECT U.Exercicio,
           U.IdGiaContribuinte,
           U.InscricaoEstadual,
           U.Cnpj,
           Ranking = CAST(U.Ranking AS VARCHAR) + '°',
           U.Variacao
      FROM (

                SELECT Contribuinte = Gia.IdGiaContribuinte,
                       ContribuinteIE = Gia.InscricaoEstadual,
                       ContribuinteCNPJ = Gia.Cnpj,
                       Ano = Vaf.Exercicio,
                       Va = Vaf.ValorAdicionado,
                       Vaf.Variacao
                  FROM VafEmpresaResumoVA Vaf
            INNER JOIN GiaContribuinte Gia ON Gia.IdGiaContribuinte = Vaf.IdGiaContribuinte
                 WHERE Exercicio IN (2017,2016,2015,2014)
                   AND Vaf.IdVafValorAdicionadoTipo = @IdVafValorAdicionadoTipo
                   AND (Vaf.IdGiaContribuinte = @IdGiaContribuinte OR 0 = @IdGiaContribuinte)
                   AND (
                            (@IdGrupoContribuinte = 0)
                        OR
                            EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                               FROM GrupoContribuinteItem Gci
                              WHERE Gci.IdGiaContribuinte = Vaf.IdGiaContribuinte
                                AND Gci.IdGrupoContribuinte = @IdGrupoContribuinte)
                        )
            ) AS A
      PIVOT (

            SUM(A.Va) FOR 
            A.Ano IN (Exercicio,IdGiaContribuinte, InscricaoEstadual, Cnpj, ValorAdicionado, Ranking, VariacaoPercentual)

      ) AS U
  ORDER BY Exercicio, InscricaoEstadual
```

O mesmo esta retornando:

```
Mensagem 8114, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 38
Error converting data type nvarchar to int.
Mensagem 473, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 38
The incorrect value "Exercicio" is supplied in the PIVOT operator.
```

Estou utilizando agora essa função do sql server, ainda possuo duvidas quanto a estrutura, basicamente preciso transformar o valor de linhas para colunas.